# Replace variable with the value in sed - special case

Tags: bash, sed, variable, yaml

I have a kubernetes yaml file and there are 351 yaml.
So, i got the pattern, after `[space][space][space]annotations:` i want to add another key/value.

before

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    release: '{{.variable.VERSION}}'
```

after

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    k8s-app/port: "{{.service.port}}"
    release: '{{.variable.VERSION}}
```

My bash script is like this

```
annoNum=$(Checking line number of string where annotations) // 13
sed -i '$annoNuma\        k8s-app/port: "{{.service.port}}"' deployment.yml
```

I would like to replace $annoNum in sed command with that $annoNum value as 13. I have tried this [use variable in sed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command) but it's not work because there is `a` as append in sed command. I have tried `${annoNum}` but the variable is not replaced with 13 as value of $annoNum variable.

As a junior cloud engineer, i really appreciate suggestion and your help.
Thank you

Comment: `$annoNum=`... is that `$` part of the prompt? Variable assignment in bash is `variable=value`, not `$variable=value`.

Comment: sorry, it's not $annoNum

Comment: before and after updated

Comment: @NickyPuff Why not to use a normal text editor, `notepad++` for instance, just to add your key after each annotation?

Comment: There is 351 yml files with different services name for each them. I mean, i need to git clone for each service. and git push after make a change.

Comment: The Issues are that you are using single quotes for your sed command which stops the variable being expanded and then the shell not knowing that you mean the `a` to be a sed command rather than part of the variable name. Try changing `'$annoNuma\ ` to `${annoNum}'a\ ` to fix them.

Comment: A different approach would be to use `/   annotations:/a\  `  to append after annotations rather than `13a\ ` to append after line 13.

Comment: I notice you're attempting to use `//` to include a comment in Bash.  That's not legal syntax so the effect will be *entirely* different than you expect.  Please [start with a good tutorial](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) rather than just guessing what the syntax is.